# Direct3D conversion of float to 8-bit channel

Tags: floating-point, pixel, direct3d, hlsl

If i have `A8R8G8B8` render target and assign `float` number to `alpha` in return of pixel shader, how in this case 32-bit float would be converted to fit 8-bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `A8R8G8B8` format specifies a 4-channel color with 8 bits per channel.  Direct3D automatically converts return values to the specified destination format, typically in the `UNORM` range for render targets.  For 8 bits, `UNORM` encodes 256 evenly-spaced values between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.  The default rounding behavior is round-nearest, ties-to-even.